# how to catch specific pyodbc error message

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc

I trid the following code,

```
import pyodbc
try:
    pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={%s};SERVER=%s;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s' % (driver, server, database, uid, password))
except pyodbc.Error, err:
    logging.warn(err)
```

The error message format i get is

```
('HY000', "[HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.2.27' (using password: YES) (1045) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

I want to receive just the message part of the error i.e.

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.2.27'(using password: YES)
```

I dont know if I can catch errors specifically like, driver not found, host down etc..

I also tried catching errors as:

```
 except pyodbc.OperationalError, err:
    logging.warn(err)
except pyodbc.DataError, err:
    logging.warn(err)
except pyodbc.IntegrityError, err:
    logging.warn(err)
except pyodbc.ProgrammingError, err:
    logging.warn(err)
except pyodbc.NotSupportedError, err:
    logging.warn(err)
except pyodbc.DatabaseError, err:
    logging.warn(err)
except pyodbc.Error, err:
    logging.warn(err)
```

but the last one always catches the error.

Fruthermore i saw the **pyodbc.Error.message** is always empty.
How can i get just the message in the error.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

pyodbc seems to just wrap the errors/exceptions from the underlying ODBC implementation, so it's unlikely that you will be able to do this.

Answer (score 56):

This worked for me.

```
    try:
        cnxn = pyodbc.connect(...)
    except pyodbc.Error as ex:
        sqlstate = ex.args[0]
        if sqlstate == '28000':
            print("LDAP Connection failed: check password")
```

There are different SQLSTATES and you can have if-else statements to print out the cause.

Similarly,

```
  try:
        cnxn = pyodbc.connect(...)
  except pyodbc.Error as ex:
        sqlstate = ex.args[1]
        print(sqlstate)
```

will give you the second part of the error with description. 
For example`ex.args[0]` give you `28000` and `ex.args[1]` gives `[28000] LDAP authentication failed for user 'user' (24) (SQLDriverConnect)`

You can then use String manipulation techniques there to just print out what you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: This also works with `pypyodbc`, when you replace `pyodbc` with the correct library name.

Answer (score 8):

It's been very long since op asked this question, but here goes a snippet of code to parse out pyodbc error messages into nice Python exceptions that can be used. This is also meant to be extended, I didn't handle every possible sqlserver error code.

```py
import re
from enum import Enum, IntEnum, unique


class PyODBCError(Exception):
    """
    Handle errors for PyODBC. Offers a error message parser
    to apply specific logic depending on the error raise

    ODBC error identifier: 23000

    pyodbc_error_message (str) -- message raised by PyODBC
        Example:
            [23000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server] \
            Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table \
            'building' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
            (544) (SQLExecDirectW) \
    """

    error_pattern = re.compile(
        r"\[(?P<error_id>.*?)\] \[(?P<operator>.*?)\]\[(?P<driver>.*?)\]\[(?P<database_type>.*?)\](?P<error_message>.+?(?= \()) \((?P<sql_server_error_id>\d*?)\) \(SQLExecDirectW\)"
    )
    sql_error_code_pattern = re.compile(r"\((?P<sql_server_error_code>\d*?)\) \(SQLExecDirectW\)")
    column_pattern = re.compile(r"column \'(?P<column_name>.+?)\'")
    table_pattern = re.compile(r"table \'(?P<table_name>.+?)\'")
    pyodbc_error_code = 'HY000'

    def __init__(self, pyodbc_error_message: str) -> None:
        self._parse_error_message(pyodbc_error_message)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.error_message

    def _parse_error_message(self, pyodbc_error_message: str) -> None:
        m = re.match(self.error_pattern, pyodbc_error_message)
        self.operator = m.group('operator')
        self.error_id = m.group('error_id')
        self.driver = m.group('driver')
        self.database_type = m.group('database_type')
        self.error_message = m.group('error_message')
        self.sql_server_error_id = m.group('sql_server_error_id')

    @classmethod
    def get_message(cls, pyodbc_exception: Exception) -> str:
        if pyodbc_exception.args[1] == cls.pyodbc_error_code:
            return pyodbc_exception.args[0]
        else:
            return pyodbc_exception.args[1]

    @classmethod
    def get_pyodbc_code(cls, pyodbc_exception: Exception) -> str:
        if pyodbc_exception.args[1] == cls.pyodbc_error_code:
            return pyodbc_exception.args[1]
        else:
            return pyodbc_exception.args[0]

    @staticmethod
    def get_exception(error_code: int):
        return {
            515: IdentityInsertNull,
            544: IdentityInsertSetToOff,
            2627: PrimaryKeyViolation,
            8114: FailedTypeConversion,
            102: IncorrectSyntax,
            32: InvalidNumberParametersSupplied
        }.get(error_code, DefaultException)

    @classmethod
    def get_sql_server_error_code(cls, pyodbc_code: str, message: str) -> int:
        """
        Parses error message raised by PyODBC and return SQL Server Error Code

        Looks for the following pattern:
            (544) (SQLExecDirectW) -> 544

        Args:
            pyodbc_error_message (str): Error string raised by PyODBC

        Returns:
            (int) - SQL Server Error Code
        """

        if pyodbc_code == cls.pyodbc_error_code:
            return 32
        else:
            m = re.search(cls.sql_error_code_pattern, message)
            if m:
                return int(m.group('sql_server_error_code'))
            else:
                raise ValueError(f"Error raised is not from SQL Server: {message}")

    @classmethod
    def build_pyodbc_exception(cls, pyodbc_exception: Exception):
        pyodbc_code = cls.get_pyodbc_code(pyodbc_exception)
        error_message = cls.get_message(pyodbc_exception)
        error_code = cls.get_sql_server_error_code(pyodbc_code, error_message)
        exception = cls.get_exception(error_code)
        raise exception(error_message)
class IdentityInsertNull(PyODBCError):
    """
    Handle specific PyODBC error related to Null Value Inserted on Identity Column
    """

    def __init__(self, pyodbc_error_message):
        super().__init__(pyodbc_error_message)
        m = re.search(self.table_pattern, self.error_message)
        self.table_name = m.group('table_name')
        m = re.search(self.column_pattern, self.error_message)
        self.column_name = m.group('column_name')


class IdentityInsertSetToOff(PyODBCError):
    """
    Handle specific PyODBC error related to Identity Not Set to On/Off
    """

    def __init__(self, pyodbc_error_message):
        super().__init__(pyodbc_error_message)
        m = re.search(self.table_pattern, self.error_message)
        self.table_name = m.group('table_name')


class FailedTypeConversion(PyODBCError):
    """
    Handle specific PyODBC error related to data type conversion
    """

    def __init__(self, pyodbc_error_message):
        super().__init__(pyodbc_error_message)


class PrimaryKeyViolation(PyODBCError):
    """
    Handle specific PyODBC error related to Primary Key Violation
    """

    def __init__(self, pyodbc_error_message):
        super().__init__(pyodbc_error_message)


class IncorrectSyntax(PyODBCError):
    """
    Handle specific PyODBC error related to incorrect syntax in query
    """

    def __init__(self, pyodbc_error_message):
        super().__init__(pyodbc_error_message)


class DefaultException(PyODBCError):
    """
    Handle default PyODBC errors
    """

    def __init__(self, pyodbc_error_message):
        super().__init__(pyodbc_error_message)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.sql_server_error_id} - {self.error_message}"


class InvalidNumberParametersSupplied(Exception):
    def __init__(self, error_message) -> None:
        self.message = error_message

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.message
```

Comment: Changed `m = re.match()` into `m = re.search()` and it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In pyodbc 3.0.7, it works fine to catch pyodbc.ProgrammingError (and presumably the other error types, although I haven't tried). The contents of the error are still sort of cryptic, though, so it may be hard to do finer-grained handling of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Worked on me:

```
try:
    """Code to catch error"""

except Exception as e:
    sqlstate = e.args[0]
    if "42000" in sqlstate:
        print("This is ProgrammingError")
    elif "23000" in sqlstate:
        print("This is IntegrityError.")
```

The number is represents the error from `pyodbc`.

Answer (score 0):

this will give you more clear and readable error message when connecting to mssql using myodbc:

```
try:
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(...)
except pyodbc.Error as ex:
    sqlstate = ex.args[1]
    sqlstate = sqlstate.split(".")
    print(sqlstate[-3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Be carreful it looks like an pyodbc exceptions but it may not be:

- In my case I read pyodbc.IntegrityError in "*(pyodbc.IntegrityError) ('23000', '[23000]...*"
- In the python console I can read this: "***sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError**: (pyodbc.IntegrityError) ('23000', '[23000]...*"
  It is actually a sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError exception, which wraps an pyodbc.IntegrityError