# How Do I Use an SQL IN Clause as a Parameter

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas

I have tried to compose an SQL IN clause using python and pandas and using the SQL profiler I find the following is passed from my python program to SQL server but no data is returned - I assume it is generating an internal error because of bad formatting but I can not identify the issue:

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=NULL
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 nvarchar(22)',N'
               SELECT [Date], [Person], [Amount]
               FROM [Logs].[dbo].[Results]
               WHERE [Date] >= GETDATE()-1 AND [Person] IN @P1',N'(''person1'', ''person2'')'
select @p1
```

Can anyone help me identify what is wrong?

Comment: What is the python code you're executing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a bunch of different things here in order to diagnose the problem:

1. Save your query to a string variable, print it, and run it against the database.
2. If the above step returns results, then the problem is not with your query. I would then check the database configuration you
   have in place in your python script/configuration file.
3. If the db configuration seems correct, add a try
   and except block to capture more details regarding any exception
   that occurs.

If you are using pyodbc check out the following link to
see how you can handle errors:

[how to catch specific pyodbc error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392709/how-to-catch-specific-pyodbc-error-message)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can specify an "IN" string as a parameter like that. This however will work in sql server. If its not sql find the similar function, or write your own.

```
AND [Person] IN (select * from string_split(@P1,','))
```

Comment: I can't use that function because of the DB compatability level, and I can't change that either.

Comment: There are a bunch of functions you can write to do the same thing - just search for splitting a CSV list into a table. Then use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

After some review and a quick chat with the dbadmin I have decided that it is simply easier for me to use python to dynamically build my query. Thanks for your efforts.