# How to check the syntax of a sql query statement before executing it in python?

Tags: python, sql

As the title says, I want to check the syntax of a query just before executing it in Python.
For example, a function named `check_syntax`:

```py
correct_sql = "select * from table;"
wrong_sql = "selecccct * from table;"

check_syntax(correct_sql) # return True 
check_syntax(wrong_sql)   # return False
```

I wonder, is there any library in Python that can help? I have looked into `sqlparse`, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

This might be un-ideal but you could do:

```py
def check_syntax(request: str) -> bool:
    try:
        cursor.execute(request)
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

The problem is that you would not "only check" the syntax. What you could is doing the same but parsing the error message `e` (`except Exception as e`) and only returning `False` if the error code is 102: IncorrectSyntax.

[Here is something that could help to parse the exception messages of pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63511349/11092636), but depending on what library you use, you'd have to change the class.

Answer (score 1):

pyparsing includes a [SELECT statement parser in its examples directory](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/select_parser.py). You could use it like this:

```
from pyparsing import Optional, ParseException
from select_parser import select_stmt

def check_syntax(s):
    try:
        (select_stmt + Optional(';')).parseString(s, parseAll=True)
    except ParseException as pe:
        print(pe.explain())
        return False
    else:
        return True

correct_sql = "select * from table;"
wrong_sql = "selecccct * from table;"

print(check_syntax(correct_sql))  # return True
print(check_syntax(wrong_sql))  # return False
```